# R data.table : How to get all distinguished values in a data.table column?

Tags: r, data.table

I want to get all distinguished values from one column of a data.table. Any help please ?

I want to a function
   Distinguished_Name (DataTable, "Categories")
that returns "cat1" and "cat2"

where

```
 DataTable <- data.table(Items = c("item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", "item6", "item7"),
                  Categories = c("cat1", "cat1", "cat1", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2", "cat2"))

 DataTable
   Items Categories
1: item1       cat1
2: item2       cat1
3: item3       cat1
4: item4       cat2
5: item5       cat2
6: item6       cat2
7: item7       cat2
```

Many thanks.

Comment: `DataTable[, unique(Categories)]` or just `unique(DataTable$Categories)` in base R

Comment: For `Distinguished_Name(DataTable, 'Categories')` to work as written, you can define the function as `Distinguished_Name <- function(df, col) unique(df[[col]])`